# Merge Javascript function to maintain postback with a fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

My goal is to have a GridView inside a div have the fixed header work as well as maintain scroll position after postback. I have two functions that work separately, but as I know little about Javascript syntax, I am having trouble merging the functions. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Relevant code:

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> //FUNCTION 1 Static Header
                    function MakeStaticHeader(gridId, height, width, headerHeight, isFooter) {
                        var tbl = document.getElementById(gridId);
                        if (tbl) {
                            var DivHR = document.getElementById('DivHeaderRow');
                            var DivMC = document.getElementById('DivMainContent');
                            var DivFR = document.getElementById('DivFooterRow');

                            //*** Set divheaderRow Properties ****
                            DivHR.style.height = headerHeight + 'px';
                            DivHR.style.width = (parseInt(width) - 0) + 'px';
                            DivHR.style.position = 'relative';
                            DivHR.style.top = '0px';
                            DivHR.style.zIndex = '10';
                            DivHR.style.verticalAlign = 'top';
                            DivHR.style.alignContent = 'center';

                            //*** Set divMainContent Properties ****
                            DivMC.style.width = width + 'px';
                            DivMC.style.height = height + 'px';
                            DivMC.style.position = 'relative';
                            DivMC.style.top = -headerHeight + 'px';
                            DivMC.style.zIndex = '1';
                            //****Copy Header in divHeaderRow****
                            DivHR.appendChild(tbl.cloneNode(true));
                        }
                    }



                    function OnScrollDiv(Scrollablediv) {
                        document.getElementById('DivHeaderRow').scrollLeft = Scrollablediv.scrollLeft;
                    }


                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript"> // FUNCTION 2 Maintain Scroll
                    window.onload = function () {
                        var h = document.getElementById("<%=hfScrollPosition.ClientID%>");
                        document.getElementById("<%=DivMainContent.ClientID%>").scrollTop = h.value;
                    }
                    function SetDivPosition() {
                        var intY = document.getElementById("<%=DivMainContent.ClientID%>").scrollTop;
                        var h = document.getElementById("<%=hfScrollPosition.ClientID%>");
                        h.value = intY;
                   }

                function afterpostback() {
                var h = document.getElementById("<%=hfScrollPosition.ClientID%>");
                document.getElementById("<%=DivMainContent.ClientID%>").scrollTop = h.value;
                }
                </script>

                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfScrollPosition" runat="server" Value="0" />

                   <div style="overflow: hidden;" id="DivHeaderRow"></div>
                    <div style="overflow: scroll;" onscroll="SetDivPosition()" id="DivMainContent" runat="server">
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ....> </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
```

[image: a]
[image: a]

Answer (score 0):

A HUGE simple fix. Just added

```
<div style="overflow: scroll;" onscroll="SetDivPosition(); OnScrollDiv(this)" id="DivMainContent" runat="server">
```

Focusing specifically on `OnScrollDiv(this)` added in the function. Works like a charm.